# React JS and TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a weird TypeError in my React code

[image]

Given below is the code snippet where I am passing the components:

```
function Home(props) {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row align-items-start">
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.dish} isLoading={props.dishesLoading} errMess={props.dishesErrMess}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.promotion} isLoading={props.promoLoading} errMess={props.promoErrMess} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.leader} isLoading={props.leadersLoading} errMess={props.leadersErrMess} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

What is even more weird is that, if I remove either the second div where I'm passing the promotions or the third div where I'm passing the leader; the code seems to work fine without showing any error and the web page is rendered.

Any explanation on why this is happening and a possible solution is much appreciated.

The code snippet of RenderCard if necessary:

```
function RenderCard({ item, isLoading, errMess }) {

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <Loading />
        );
    }
    else if (errMess) {
        return (
            <h4>{errMess}</h4>
        );
    }
    else
        return (
            <FadeTransform in transformProps={{exitTransform: 'scale(0.5) translateY(-50%)'}}>
                <Card>
                    <CardImg src={baseUrl + item.image} alt={item.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                        {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle> : null}
                        <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </FadeTransform>
        );
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that it's telling you that it tried to access the property `image` of an undefined value?  That is likely happening at `item.image`.  So just do some debugging and assert that it's not undefined - you'll likely discover that your assertion is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying `item` is `undefined`, so it cannot read a property "image" from undefined.

I'm gonna go ahead and say that one/some/all of these props is undefined

```
<RenderCard item={props.dish}
<RenderCard item={props.promotion}
<RenderCard item={props.leader}
```

Comment: But why would the page render if either one of them is not present?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Javascript is not a type safe language, so it doesn't know `item` is undefined until runtime. So while it's rendering things it can render, it notices there's a line that essentially goes `undefined.image` which is invalid and crashes. Perphaps adding a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of `RenderCard` would help you debug the `props.item` variable

Answer (score 0):

```js
function RenderCard({ item, isLoading, errMess }) {

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <Loading />
    );
  }
  else if (errMess) {
    return (
      <h4>{errMess}</h4>
    );
  }
  else
    return (item ? <FadeTransform in transformProps={{ exitTransform: 'scale(0.5) translateY(-50%)' }}>
      <Card>
        <CardImg src={baseUrl + item.image} alt={item.name} />
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
          {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle> : null}
          <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </FadeTransform> : null
    );
}
```

Check it the item property exist and render the component or return null

Comment: I'd argue `item` should never be `undefined` if the code execution go pass `loading` and `error`, for a solid architecture

Comment: I totally agree with you, it was more about pointing out the issue than making it a final solution